# Алгоритм оптимизации маршрута

Tags: алгоритм, java

Здравствуйте, можете подсказать какой-то не особо заумный алгоритм оптимизации машрута! Если детальней описать проблему, то у меня имеется какой-то маршрут, и я знаю все расстояния между каждой точкой и всеми остальными. В результате *мне нужно получить длину маршрута меньше, чем была до того, как мы его оптимизировали*. То есть обход по тем же точкам должен получиться меньше по общей длине маршрута. Как вообще сравнивать между собой ближайшие точки, есть ли какая-то теорема что ли, которая позволяет сделать меньше затрат в операциях и, следовательно, в коде, или нужно изобретать свой велосипед? Мне нужно будет реализовать это на Java.

Comment: А все точки маршрута надо использовать?

Comment: ну да, начальная и конечная - одинаковые, то есть это одна и та же точка

Comment: Учи мат.часть :) Это дискретная математика :)

Answer (score 2):

Описанная Вами задача идеально подходит под алгоритм поиска минимального остовного дерева.
Все точки представте в виде вершин графа, пути между точками - ребра графа. Вес каждого ребра - это расстояние между точками. Далее применяете алгоритм поиска минимального остовного дерева, мне больше всего нравиться [Крускал с системой непересекающихся множеств](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/mst_kruskal_with_dsu). Можете также погуглить "минимальное остовное дерево".

UPD: Все наврал, описанная задача - [задача коммивояжёра](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B6%D1%91%D1%80%D0%B0)

Comment: ага, спасибо, похоже на правду)) ща почитаю

Comment: Мне кажется, что тут скорее задача комивояжера, т.к. требуется найти именно путь (обход)

Comment: да, когда ответили что первая и последняя совпадают, сам понял )

Comment: да, это действительно будет задача коммивояжера в замкнутом виде, ну а идею с графом можете взять свыше)

Comment: Ну я так почитал, сделал такие выводы! Так как у меня маршрут может состоять больше чем с 5 точек, то алгоритм комивояжера не подходит, потомучто он будет очень долго перебирать все варианты... А алгоритм Краскала расчитан для незамкнутых графов-это во первых, во вторых, может я не правильно понял, но мне кажется, что ребра, оптимизированных с его помощью маршрутов, будут пересекаться, а мне это никак не подходит!!! Скажите, пожалуйста где я туплю или другой какой-то выход!!!

Comment: аааа...нет,нет! Я просто не мог до конца понять алгоритм. Все нормально, Крускал подходит, просто по той ссылке, которую вы дали, невозможно понять суть его, там плохо описан алгоритм. Детальное и понятное его описание я нашел только вот здесь http://www.algolib.narod.ru/Graph/Ostov.html 
Только по этой ссылке он уже называется не Краскала, а Дейкстры-Прима!!Нипанятна)))
Нужно будет еще придумать как замкнуть маршрут после оптимизации таким способом, но я не думаю что этот будет сложно.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую начать с алгоритма дейкстры, он проще в понимании:
[дейкстра на википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B)

Comment: Да я уже и сам понял что проще, читай коментарий мой выше! Он наверное скрыт был, поэтому ты не видел, но все равно СПАСИБО!!)))